# PHP function not respecting parameter

Tags: php, function, parameters, arguments

If I have a php function like so:

```
function doSomething($arg1, $arg2, $arg3 = null) {}
```

And I call it like this:

```
doSomething('Hello', 'Goodbye', 'Something else');
```

Why would the 3rd parameter ($arg3) not respect what's passed to it?
Could there be a specific reason?

If I define a parameter within the function itself it works fine, ie:

```
function doSomething($arg1, $arg2, $arg3 = 'This will be set properly now') {}
```

But I can't pass anything to the function. I get no error, but the 3rd parameter will always be null no matter what I pass to it.
In my particular circumstance, it's always taking the default value instead of the value I'm trying to pass in.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: works for me, https://3v4l.org/bLBhl

Comment: also works for me  https://eval.in/692373

Comment: will you show your code

Comment: PHP will respect that parameter, if you send it one.